# Poor Google Docs printing quality

Tags: google-docs

Why is it that all text printouts I make with Google Docs look poor?

This has been an ongoing phenomenon for years, in many different workplaces. Still, I see no discussion of this problem online. Everything looks fine when displayed on screen, but in printed form, the spacing of the letters is a little wrong. The text is readable, but the space for each letter is somewhat wrong.

*Note: If I first export the document to PDF and then print it from a PDF viewer program, then the printout looks fine.*

I only use the default font (Arial) and haven't messed with the settings. I have no printing problems with other programs.

Comment: Yes, I noticed the exact same thing just yet. We are looking to use Google Docs for our newsletter and made a beautiful template for this, but when printing things look awful.

Underlining words or links have the line shifted from the word, text is placed out of bound, spacing between characters is wrong (sometimes letters are closer to the next word than the word it belongs too). I tried using different fonts like Calibra and Verdana, but the problems remain...

Comment: @Dag Wieers: It's baffling that so few users are able to notice this problem and that it apparently remains unresolved to this day. My advice is to generate PDFs first, and print them.